# What's the word meaning the use of the wrong word?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word meaning the use of the wrong word?

For instance, calling a "theft" a "robbery".

Comment: _Theft_ and _robbery_ mean the same thing outside a law court, where they **may** have different meanings.

Comment: @JohnLawler Even in the law, *robbery* is a subset of *theft*. It involves a *theft* where threat of bodily harm is likely (at least in the US).

Comment: @bib, that's so from a criminal justice point of view, but in English sometimes _robbery_ isn't even illegal, as in the phrase _daylight robbery_, meaning charging an excessive price for something.

Comment: @BrianHooper Yeah, and I felt like that scheming store owner was holding me up at gunpoint!

Comment: As is often the case, the example OP gives is less than helpful, provoking more discussion than the question. I **thought** that J Lawler's comment was satisfactory, but the three major dictionaries I checked all stipulate that robbery involves a nasty confrontation (you can't be a 'sneak-robber').

Answer (score 7):

One form of wrong-word-use is *[malapropism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malapropism)*

> the unintentional misuse of a word by confusion with one of similar sound, esp when creating a ridiculous effect, as in *I am not under the affluence of alcohol*

Another is *[misnomer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misnomer?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> an incorrect or unsuitable name or term for a person or thing

And there is always that broader explanation (not limited to simple word substitution) by politicians, that they *[misspoke](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misspeak?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> to speak incorrectly, improperly, or misleadingly

Answer (score 6):

A little uncommon, but it's really specific for what you need: *[catachresis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catachresis)*:

> A misuse of a word; an application of a term to something which it does not properly denote.

Answer (score -1):

**Malapropos**:

> in an inopportune or inappropriate way.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/malapropos)</sub>

Comment: Hi Liberty, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system will certainly flag it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a source for your definition, explain why *malapropos* suits the context and perhaps say something about how commonly it's used. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)